# how to generate a report in sql server from a previous select

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2016

Periodically I need to generate a report based on some data from database.

The first select IS:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
                 A.PRO_C_NOME,
                 B.ETS_C_NOME        
                FROM WETI_ETAPA_ITEM F   
                 INNER JOIN WETE_ETAPA_ITEM_EDITORS E   
                  ON E.ETE_N_ETI_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WETA_ETAPA_PROCESSO H   
                  ON H.ETA_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_ETA_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WIPR_ITEM_PROCESSO C   
                  ON C.IPR_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_IPR_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WIWF_ITEM_WORKFLOW D  
                  ON D.IWF_N_CODIGO = C.IPR_N_IWF_N_CODIGO  
                 INNER JOIN WPRO_PROCESSO A    
                  ON A.PRO_N_CODIGO = C.IPR_N_PRO_N_CODIGO AND PRO_N_DELETED = 0  
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN WISP_ITEM_SUBPROCESS G    
                  ON G.ISP_N_ID = F.ETI_ISP_N_ID
                 INNER JOIN WETS_ETAPA_SLA B
                  ON F.ETI_N_ETS_N_CODIGO = B.ETS_N_CODIGO
```

Returns something like this:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |

I need a report from that first select returning something like this:

| S.1 | S.2 | S.3 | S.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 0 |

that is:

S.1 - distinct values from C1
S.2 - count 1 values in C2 for the S.1 value
S.3 - count 2 values in C2 for the S.1 value
S.4 - count 3 values in C2 for the S.1 value

Can someone help how do I solve this?

I tried many solutions, such as using temporary tables and selecting from another select but doesn't work at all for different reasons.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry. what is the correct form to represent a table in a question?

Comment: DDL and DML are the *best* way (for a SQL related question), however, a markdown table is still acceptable.

Comment: You mention a `SELECT` in your question; what is that statement? Thought this looks like pivoting/conditional aggregation. Have you had a look at the examples from those? You state you've "tried many solution" but they "doesn't work"; what were those attempts? *Why* didn't they work?

Comment: Do you *need* all of those `JOIN`s? The `DISTINCT` looks like you are handling a many to one/many relationship and filtering out duplicates because of that relationship. As you don't ever reference the object aliased a `G` anywhere other than the `LEFT JOIN`, why is it included at all? Most of those `INNER JOIN`s would likely be better off as an `EXISTS`, while to `JOIN` to `WISP_ITEM_SUBPROCESS` can be completely removed. Then you can (also) remove the (potentially very) expensive `DISTINCT` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte(PRO_C_NOME, ETS_C_NOME)  as (
SELECT DISTINCT
                 A.PRO_C_NOME,
                 B.ETS_C_NOME        
                FROM WETI_ETAPA_ITEM F   
                 INNER JOIN WETE_ETAPA_ITEM_EDITORS E   
                  ON E.ETE_N_ETI_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WETA_ETAPA_PROCESSO H   
                  ON H.ETA_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_ETA_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WIPR_ITEM_PROCESSO C   
                  ON C.IPR_N_CODIGO = F.ETI_N_IPR_N_CODIGO   
                 INNER JOIN WIWF_ITEM_WORKFLOW D  
                  ON D.IWF_N_CODIGO = C.IPR_N_IWF_N_CODIGO  
                 INNER JOIN WPRO_PROCESSO A    
                  ON A.PRO_N_CODIGO = C.IPR_N_PRO_N_CODIGO AND PRO_N_DELETED = 0  
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN WISP_ITEM_SUBPROCESS G    
                  ON G.ISP_N_ID = F.ETI_ISP_N_ID
                 INNER JOIN WETS_ETAPA_SLA B
                  ON F.ETI_N_ETS_N_CODIGO = B.ETS_N_CODIGO
)

    SELECT PRO_C_NOME AS 'S.1'
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN ETS_C_NOME=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'S.2'
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN ETS_C_NOME=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'S.3'
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN ETS_C_NOME=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'S.4'
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY PRO_C_NOME
```

Comment: it doesnot worked: Column 'WPRO_PROCESSO.PRO_C_NOME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: see my edit, did you forget to add it to group by?